# sql backup restore converts createdAt to local TZ

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, timezone, backup

I have a remote MySQL DB in the cloud on JAWSDB.

I have `createdAt` and `updatedAt` timestamps for records that are in UTC TZ.

I'll backup these DBs using `mysqldump -h HOST -u USER -p > backup.sql`. I then restore these to a local MySQL Server using
`mysql -u USERNAME -p DB_NAME < backup.sql`

However, upon inspecting the new local backup...I notice that the `createdAt` timestamps are for my local TZ (EST and so currently 5hrs before the UTC version that are actually in JAWSDB). The `updatedAt` timestamps are still in `UTC` though.

Here's how I created those timestamp fields btw.

```
 `createdAt` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updatedAt` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

So it seems like the restore of the dump is converting from UTC to EST just for the `createdAt` field. Could this be due to an engine or mysql version mismatch between JawsDB and my local server?

Any insights? Thanks!